# Sharepoint PnP & SPFX React

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core

While binding the data always getting extra row ...

```
 {this.state.items.map(myitems1 => {
            return (
              <div key={myitems1.Id}>
                <span>{myitems1.Item_x0020_Name}</span>
                <button onClick={e => this.dosometing(myitems1.Id)}>
                  Offline
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

### Heading

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your collection has four items in it. The first one has an empty value in the Item_x0020_Name field.

Comment: but , I dont want to show that line . what to do ? please help